# Selenium Server on CentOS 6.2 has no keyboard input while testing

Tags: firefox, selenium, keyboard, centos

We currently have a problem with **SeleniumServer** which is troubling me for 2 days, now...hope you can help me.

**The Selenium Server** is running on a **CentOS 6.2**, **Selenium Server is 2.21** and **Firefox is 10.0.4**.

When a test is starting up, **SeleniumServer** launches **Firefox** but he can not type anything in the form fields or press "Enter" to submit.

Even better, no one (not even me with **VNC-Server**) can write something in the form field, url bar, menus, press a key like "Enter", etc....it is as the keyboard is not present... It´s like **Firefox** is locked somehow.

If a start **Firefox** with **Interactive-Mode** : `selenium-server.jar -interactive` & `cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox&2=http://www.google.com` everything is working fine, I can do all the tests manually.

I can also start firefox manually with just typing `firefox` in the shell and that is working fine, too.

So what is going on in **Selenium** and how does **Selenium** starts **Firefox**? Why is no **Keyboard-Input** available when running a **Selenium-Test** with **SeleniumServer**?
We tested with **MacOS** and **Windows**, too and both working fine with the same test.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Greetings from Berlin

Comment: serverfault.com question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself with an older version of Firefox. Firefox 7 worked for me.